# Vector combination results in every possible vector

Tags: vectors

Apparently, the following 3 vectors can be combined using various scalar quantities to make every single possible vector in $\Bbb R^3$:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\-3\\\end{pmatrix}$$ $$\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\3\\\end{pmatrix}$$ $$\begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\\3\\\end{pmatrix}$$
How the heck do I show this? Where do I even start?

Comment: do you meant $$\alpha[1;2;-3]+\beta[1;-2;3]+\gamma[-1;2;3]=[x;y;z]$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\vec{u}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\-3\\\end{pmatrix}$$ $$\vec{v}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\3\\\end{pmatrix}$$ $$\vec{w}=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\\3\\\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\z \end{pmatrix}=\frac{x}{2}(\vec{u}+\vec{v})+\frac{y}{4}(\vec{u}+\vec{w})+\frac{z}{6}(\vec{v}+\vec{w})$$

Comment: I know this is true already, but how do I show that apart from trial and error?

Comment: The three given vectors are linearly independent and form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. So, $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}$ can be written in terms of the three given vectors. Adding any two of them will cancel out two of the three entries. This gives us a hint.

Comment: You may have known this, but you can render $\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}$ more succinctly with `\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you have already seen or already know, there are quick and more tedious ways to show this. It suffices to show, for example, that these three vectors are *linearly independent*; either from the definition or e.g. by calculating the determinant and verifying it is non-zero:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 \\
2 & -2 & 2 \\
-3 & 3 & 3 
\end{vmatrix} =\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & -4 & 4 \\
-3 & 6 & 0 
\end{vmatrix} = -4\cdot 6 = -24 \ne 0$$
The *direct way* usually requires a bit more work, but that means you want to show that:
$$\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}=
\alpha\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ -3\end{pmatrix}
+\beta\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -2 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}
+\gamma\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}$$
always has a solution for $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ in terms of (arbitrary) $x,y,z$. This gives you a system of 3 linear equations in 3 unknowns; you can solve with a method of your choice:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} \alpha+\beta-\gamma &=& x \\
2\alpha-2\beta+2\gamma &=& y \\
-3\alpha+3\beta+3\gamma &=& z \end{array}\right.$$

In general this direct method is more tedious, unless you can solve it in a faster or more clever way, e.g. *by inspection* (see CY Aries's answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could try giving an explicit formula, as CY Aries does in CY Aries's answer.

The way to arrive at this is as follows: let's say your target vector is $(x,y,z)$. You want to find scalars $a,b,c$ (depending on your target vector) such that:
$$ \begin{align}
1a + 1b + (-1)c &= x \\
2a + (-2)b + 2c &= y \\
(-3)a + 3b + 3c &= z \\
\end{align} $$

This is a system of linear equations that you can solve using tools you (hopefully) know. It's a little cumbersome, but not terrible.

Alternatively, if you're familiar with some linear algebra, it's enough to show that these vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: So it's the fact that these vectors are so called "linearly independent" that makes this outcome possible?

Comment: @Thestrugglingstudent How much linear algebra are you familiar with? A set of vectors is called a "basis" for some space $V$ if they can be combined to form every vector in $V$. So your question is asking to show this set is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. There's an important theorem in linear algebra that, in an $n$-dimensional space, any set of $n$ linearly independent vectors is a basis for the space. So this theorem is what makes it possible.

Comment: Yeah, you see I know absolutely nothing about this. I'm a first year undergrad and this is a problem I'm havig to face when we've barely even started the course about Matrix Albegra. Nevertheless, thank you very much; at least I know what I need to show now

Comment: @Thestrugglingstudent Okay, then do it the explicit way like CV Aries -- it's not too bad. In time, you'll learn about the concepts of basis, linear independence, and dimension.

Comment: @Thestrugglingstudent I just saw your comment on CV Aries's answer that you were bothered by trial and error. I've edited my answer and added the method for how to do it if you don't know any linear algebra. It's a little cumbersome (in fact, one of the advantages of linear algebra and matrices is to make processes just like this easier!), but not terrible in this case.